# Enable event tracking for Google Translator (TranslateElement) with Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-translate

Migration from Google Analytics 3 to 4 I wonder how to replace the following Google Translator script:

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL,
        gaTrack: true,
        gaId: 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX'
    }, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

In Google Analytics 4 I have an GTM-XXXXXXXX ID and a numeric property ID. Can not test this until deployed to production, otherwise I would just try it out. How to correctly replace the `gaTrack` and `gaId` for Google translate? Which ID to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12270356?hl=en

1. Go to Admin -> [Your Property] -> Data Streams
2. Copy the "Measurement ID" (not the stream ID) which looks like `G-XXXXXXXXX` and put it as value of the `gaId` parameter